# How do you send HTTP requests to Tor hidden services in Go?

Tags: go, hidden, tor

There is a hidden service that has a "Online Users" counter and it gets the number of online users using a get request to an API on the hidden service. I thought it would be interesting to monitor how many online users there are at different points in the day, but I would like to try and simply send the HTTP GET request using a SOCKS5 proxy instead of installing the Tor proxy software locally and using it on 127.0.0.1. I am just a bit lost really, I did research and I know that you need to connect to a SOCKS proxy before you can query a hidden service, and I've been looking into Golang's /x/net/proxy library for an easy way to use this.

I'm not too sure on where to start if I'm being honest. I have a lot of the building blocks I believe thought out. I know I will need to use SOCKS to connect to a public proxy and then send a GET request through this proxy to the desired hidden service, but I'm not sure where to find a list of public SOCKS5 proxies that I can use with Tor. **Is there even a difference between normal SOCKS5 proxies and SOCKS5 proxies that are used with Tor?**

Comment: Normal SOCKS proxies relay your connection to the target over TCP, but Tor's SOCKS proxy is a gateway to the Tor network. If you want to send an HTTP request to a Tor hidden service from Go, you'll need to talk to a Tor SOCKS proxy. There are no public Tor SOCKS proxies, you'll need to run the Tor software locally for your application to access Tor. Eventually you can use the [Arti](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/arti/) Tor Rust implementation instead of running a Tor daemon, but it's not completed yet.